# Collision Detection for sidescrolling Tile based Game

Tags: collision-detection, actionscript-3, tiles

I've been working on a tile based game with a 2d array as fundamental ground for my tiles. Now my next step is to have the wall tiles be impenetrable, so that the player can walk ontop of them and collide against their sides/bottom.

<strike>So as this is loosely based on tonyPa tutorial, it uses the corners of the player character (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right corners) to check if any corner hits a wall (walls are assigned as "1" in the 2d array). When a corner touches a tile that is recognized as "1" (wall), I want to check from what side the player is hitting, and then move the player next to the tiles side, to simulate a collision.</strike>

Now what I've noticed is, it's easy to check if any corner is touching a wall, but its harder to determine which side the corner is hitting. Because of this, my current code is not simulating a satisfying collision detection. As my hero walks on the ground, he randomly stops because the bottom corners not only touch the top of the tiles, but also the sides it seems.

#### **UPDATE**

So I changed my code based on the first answer by **bummzack**. Using center points of each side of player entity instead of each corner. And now my character slides down walls without getting stuck and walks across grounds fairly smoothly, but another problem arises. If the player jumps on a tile, and the center part of the bottom is NOT within the tiles width, he falls right through. And this is because I am just comparing a POINT (the center point specifically) and not the full bottom side against the top of the tile beneath the player.

Here's a link to the **SWF-file**, http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28271061/_TileGameFLA.swf  , X to JUMP, Z to RUN, ARROWKEYS to MOVE, which should give you a visual example of what's happening:

Here is the **UPDATED** code (all collision code is within "collisionCheck" function)

```
    private function onKEYDOWN(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        var pressedKey = event.keyCode;
        
        if(pressedKey == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            rightKey = true;
        }
        
        if(pressedKey == Keyboard.LEFT){
            leftKey = true;
        }
        if(pressedKey == Keyboard.Z){
            runKey = true;
        }
        if(pressedKey == Keyboard.X){
            jumpKey = true;
        }
    }
    
    private function onKEYUP(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        var releasedKey = event.keyCode;
        
        if(releasedKey == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            rightKey = false;
        }
        
        if(releasedKey == Keyboard.LEFT){
            leftKey = false;
        }
        if(releasedKey == Keyboard.Z){
            runKey = false;
        }
        if(releasedKey == Keyboard.X){
            jumpKey = false;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    private function collisionCheck():void{
        
        centerY = Math.floor((theHero.y + (theHero.width/2))/ts);
        centerX = Math.floor((theHero.x + (theHero.width/2))/ts);
        top = Math.floor(theHero.y / ts);
        bottom = Math.floor((theHero.y + theHero.height) / ts);
        left = Math.floor(theHero.x / ts);
        right = Math.floor((theHero.x + theHero.width) / ts);
        
        //If there is no ground under the player, start falling.
        if(curMap[bottom][centerX] != 1 && curMap[bottom][centerX] != 1){
            gravity = 3;
            onGround = false;
        }
        
        if(vy > 0 && oldBottom < bottom){
            
            if(curMap[bottom][centerX] != 0){//If either on of the bottom corners are touching a "1"-tile (a wall)
                
                theHero.y = ((bottom - 1) * ts) + 2 ;
                gravity = 0;
                vy = 0;
                onGround = true;
                jumped = false;
                jumpSpeed = 9;
                
            }
        }
        
        if(vy < 0 && oldTop > top){
            if(curMap[top][centerX] != 0){
                theHero.y = (top + 1) * ts; 
                gravity = 3;
                vy = 0;
                jumpSpeed = 0;
            }
        }
        
        if(vx < 0 && oldLeft > left ){
            if(curMap[centerY][left] != 0){
                vx = 0;
                theHero.x = (left + 1) * ts;
                
            }
        }
        trace(curMap[bottom][centerX]);
        if(vx > 0 && oldRight < right ){
            if(curMap[centerY][right] != 0 ){
                vx = 0;
                theHero.x = ((right - 1) * ts )+ 1.8; // 1.8 so it doesnt touch wall, it goes right through if its the accurate 2.0
                
            }
        }
        
    }

    
    private function moveChar():void{
        
        if(rightKey){
            if(runKey){
                vx = 7;
            }else{
                vx = 4;
            }
        }
        if(leftKey){
            if(runKey){
                vx = -7;
            }else{
                vx = -4;
            }
        }
        
        //Stand still if you're not pressing left or right ON THE GROUND (in air you should after one key press)
        if(!leftKey && !rightKey && onGround){
            vx = 0;
        }
        
        if(jumpKey && jumpSpeed > 1 && !jumped){
            vy -= jumpSpeed;
            jumpSpeed *= 0.8;
            onGround = false;
            gravity = 3;
        }
        
        
        
        
        vy += gravity;
        
        if(vy > 14){
            vy = 14;
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    private function onENTERFRAME(event:Event):void{
        
        if(myStage.stage.focus != myStage){
            myStage.stage.focus = myStage;
        }
        
        //These variables represent where the hero WAS before being moved
        //, this helps to see if hero approached the tile from the left/right/top/bottom
        //, thus gives us an additional way to check where player is coming from
        oldBottom = Math.floor((theHero.y + theHero.height) / ts);
        oldLeft = Math.floor(theHero.x / ts);
        oldRight = Math.floor(theHero.x + theHero.width) / ts;
        oldTop = Math.floor(theHero.y / ts);
        
        
        moveChar();
        
        theHero.y += vy;
        theHero.x += vx;
        
        collisionCheck();
        
        
    }

}
```

}

This is by far not the smartest way to check collisons, but I think it might work well enough. I just need someone to throw me in the right direction for making a solid collision detection engine for a simple tile based game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking the corners of your sprite, I suggest you check the midpoints. Like in this image:

[image: collision points]

The bottom "sensor" checks for ground collisions, the front checks for "wall" collisions. Usually you'll need maximum two active sensors. Examples:

- Player walks forward, *FRONT* and *BOTTOM* must be checked
- Player stands still: *BOTTOM* must be checked
- Player performs forward jump. While moving upward, *FRONT* and *TOP* must be checked, when falling, *FRONT* and *BOTTOM* must be checked.
- etc.

Comment: Ok so I did that, and now the issue is that the player will go RIGHT through the tile UNLESS the midpoint (midLeft or midRight or midBottom etc..)is touching the wall. For example if I stand under a tile, and I jump, if the midpoint of the player is touching the tile, ONLY then does it collide, but if a corner of the player is touching the tile above, he goes right through it. So this doesn't make for an airtight collision detection. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not an *airtight* collision detection by any means (it will obviously never work flawlessly against objects that are smaller than half the size of the player). You could experiment with moving your "sensors", depending on the current player movement. Otherwise you might want to look into AABB and SAT collision checking. Or read [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9144/2d-platformer-collision-handling) and [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7890/2d-object-aligned-bounding-box-intersection-test).

Comment: I am learning AABB and SAT from Metanets tutorial right now, although it seems I have to dig deeper in VECTORS and how to use them in order to apply AABB properly. But essentially, you are just looking at the width and height of the overlap rectangle, and then using that to calculate which side the player is coming from and by how much he penetrates the tile, right? (and then using that to push player back in right direction with right amount of pixels) Oh btw, I updated the code and the text with a link, take a look at the SWF and you'll see the new problems.

Comment: @Kid that sounds about right. Keep in mind that your AABB check might return several collisions (player could collides with 2 tiles). I think your collision detection as it is now works pretty good though. Maybe you could just increase the bottom and top sensors to one at each corner and be fine?

Comment: @bummzack that is what I did at first, just checking each corner. But the issue is, my character kept getting stuck everywhere. Like jumping next to a wall would make the character stick instead of sliding down. And even walking on ground the player would stop at every tile, only thing you could do was to JUMP in order to move forward. This was because the left/bottom corner would detect a non-walkable tile or the right/bottom would.

Comment: Heres a link to the SWF, the one where i check the CORNERS: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28271061/__TileGameFLAfirst.swf

Comment: @Kid I wasn't suggesting to use your old model. Keep the mid-points for *left* and *right* collision detection and only use the corners for *top* and *bottom* collision. The two bottom "sensors" would not be used to determine if the character can move forward, but just if he's standing on ground or not.

Comment: @bummzack I solved it! By using the corner system COMBINED with AABB system. So the corners of the player tell you if there is a wall there (broad phase SAT), and the AABB system checks to see from what side you might be hitting that wall(narrow phase SAT). This makes the tiles impenetrable, somewhat, you still 'cut' corners if you come in a fast speed. And this I solved with multisampling (using a for-loop within EnterFrame event, that loops 8 times and makes player take 8 small steps instead of one big + checks for collisions).

Comment: The multisample is the only thing that worries me...might cause lag or slowdown later on when the game gets heavier(?). Cause basically I am checking collisions 8 times more within ONE frame..

Comment: @Kid: Good to hear. As long as you're just sampling in the narrow phase you should be fine. I wouldn't worry about performance at this stage though. Doing multiple collision samples during one update is quite common (eg. physics engines). If that ever collision detection ever turns out to be the bottleneck (I doubt it), then you can still optimize that code later.

Comment: @bummzack Ok ok. I am glad to hear that it is regular to do multiple collision checks, I never seem fully confident that how I approach collision is the proper way :). Although I did encapsulated all the collision within one function, the corner checks (which I assume is broad phase) and the amount overlap of player vs tilewall (which I assume is narrow). And that function as a whole is being looped 12 times every frame. It's only one object against the 4 closest tiles though, should be ok(?).

Comment: @bummzack Btw, thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it. Are you a game developer yourself?

Comment: @Kid It's hard to tell if your checks are going to hurt performance without seeing code. But that would be premature optimization. *If* your game suddenly becomes slow, you can still profile and optimize later. Regarding your last comment: Yeah, I'm developing flash games and I'm starting iPhone development.

Comment: @bummzack, do you have devlog? Yeah, you're right though, I should wait until all the elements are in place and moving simultaneously, and then decided whether I should keep optimizing. I just changed my hero to move with blitting instead of moving as a Sprite now though. Has no obvious change in performance, but again, probably because the game itself is not that heavy. Yet. Do you have/Are you willing to share your Skype/MSN/AIM info?